# Motivation for Nesbitt-like substitution in inequality

Tags: inequality, contest-math

The following is a problem from page 19 of the following [collection of problems](https://web.evanchen.cc/exams/ELMO-2014-SL.pdf).

Let $a, b, c, d, e, f$ be positive real numbers. Given that $def + de + ef + fd = 4$, show that
$$ ((a + b)de + (b + c)ef + (c + a)fd)^2 \geq 12(abde + bcef + cafd) .$$

The first provided solution from [[1]](https://web.evanchen.cc/exams/ELMO-2014-SL.pdf) makes use of the following substitution: $d = \frac{2m}{n + p}, e = \frac{2n}{m + p}, f = \frac{2p}{m + n}$. While it is clear that this is a valid substitution, I cannot see how to naturally come up with it. What is the motivation behind this substitution?

Comment: 1/ Are you familiar with the condition being equivalent to $ \sum \frac{d}{d+2} = 1$? $\quad$ 2/ If we then set $ \frac{d}{d+2} = \frac{ m}{m+n+p}$, then we get $ d = \frac{2m}{n+p}$.

Comment: Alternatively, the condition is equivalent to $ \sum \frac{1}{d+2} = 1$, for which $ \frac{1}{d+2} = \frac{m}{m+n+p}$ gives us $ d = \frac{2m}{n+p}$.  $\quad$ This version is easier to derive from the conditions.

Comment: I can see why both of those are equivalent, but those too I cannot find a natural way to deduce (as in, working backwards from your equivalence to my original substitution seems quite daunting).